# Unable to overwrite the font-size in jquery tooltip

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using the jquery tooltip like below:

```
(<any>$("#MyDivId")).tooltip({
        show: {
            effect: 'slideDown'
        },
        tooltipClass: "tooltip",
        track: true,
        open: function (event:any, ui:any) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                (<any>$(ui.tooltip)).hide();
            }, waitTimeFiveSecs);
        }
    });



.tooltip{
    font-size: XXpx;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Segoe, sans-serif;
}
```

I want to display the title text in a smaller font than the one displayed by the tooltip in default. But irrespective of my assignment in the `font-size` , I see the tooltip is displaying text of same font size. How to reduce the font size here?

**Update**

On inspecting on the element I see, `ui-widget` class is overwriting my class font-size and font-family properties.

```
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: I assume you have checked in the developer console what rule is overwriting your rule.

Comment: As I try to inspect on the tooltip, it vanishes. Can you help me on, how to inspect on the tooltip to see what rules are overwriting my rules?

Comment: Rightclick the element that has the tooltip, and permanently set it in `:hover` state. https://imgur.com/a/BDK3F (Chrome example)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I updated the question. The `ui-widget` class is over writing my class properties.

Comment: As a quickfix, add `!important` at the end of your font-size and font-family definition like so: `font-size: XXpx !important;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Segoe, sans-serif !important;`

Comment: As a proper fix, you need to investigate why their rule wins over yours. Typical reasons: Last rule wins (solve by adding your CSS after the jQuery UI CSS), or their rule is more specific than yours (in this case make your selector more specific than theirs).

Comment: Thanks ! That was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

try these classes

```
.ui-tooltip-content {
    font-size: XXpx;
}

.ui-tooltip {
    font-size: XXpx;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: As he's using `Jquery UI tooltip`, these classes can be used to overwrite `css`.